# What are link "scopes" in systemd-resolved?

Tags: dns, systemd-networkd, systemd-resolved

While trying to fix a DNS issue with NetworkManager's ModemManager on Ubuntu, I came across this difference in the output of `systemd-resolve --status` when connected.  (`ping` ip works, manually editing `/etc/resolv.conf` fixes the problem, and setting FallbackDNS also fixes the problem, but all with side-effects.

**Working installation - PPP modem** (Ubuntu 17.10)

```
Link 3 (wwp0s20u6)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 198.142.0.51
                      211.29.132.12
```

**Broken installation - PPP modem** (Same hardware - Lubuntu 17.04)

```
Link 2 (wwp0s20u6)
      Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

These are both versions of Ubuntu and identical hardware.  The configs of the network connections in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` are also identical.

On links with DHCP like ethernet and Wifi adapters, the DNS scope is added to the link and DNS works correctly on both machines.  e.g.

**Broken installation - WiFi adapter working**

```
Link 3 (wlan0)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1
```

So, I speculate that it's not a problem with `systemd-resolved` itself, but with something that tells `systemd-resolved` it should be looking for DNS.

***What are systemd link "Scopes"?***

***Why would one machine assign the "DNS" scope and the other not?***

Answer (score 0):

`systemd-resolve` is a front end to the `systemd-resolved` service, which describes itself as a "Network Name Resolution manager". `systemd-resolved.service` is configured in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`. This file can contain the option `DNS=`, which should have as value a list of DNS server addresses. If this option is missing, `/etc/resolv.conf` is used instead.

`/etc/resolv.conf` in turn can be a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`, which is maintained by `systemd-resolved` itself, or `/etc/resolv.conf` can be created by some other program independently of `systemd-resolved`.

My guess is that your Lubuntu machine does not have a `DNS=` entry in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and `/etc/resolv.conf` is missing, or it does not contain DNS server entries.

LLMNR (RFC 4794) stands for "Link-Local Multicast Name Resolution", and is an alternative to DNS for resolving names. LLMNR does not have a central service, but each host responds with its own addresses when a query for a matching name is sent as a multicast datagram over the local LAN. As the name says, LLMNR is restricted to the local network; it has link-local scope. A competing protocol to LLMNR is Multicast DNS (RFC 6762).

Comment: DNS servers are in both cases supplied by the server or ModemManager.  There is no DNS= in either machine.  I tried adding DNS=8.8.8.8 and it didn't add 'DNS' to Current Scopes, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Additionally, the DNS scope *is* added to other non-ModemManager links like ethernet and WiFi adapters with DHCP.